# is not a function при попытке вызвать метод у экземпляра класса

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6

Разбираюсь с объектным ООП в js, пытаюсь создать простейший метод класса. 
Конструктор создаёт объект, но вызов метода не проходит.

```
function ProtoError (code) {
  const error={
    "1":{
      "code": 100,
      "text": "foo"
    },
   ///...
  }
  self=this
  return error[code]
 }
ProtoError.prototype.fullText = function(){
  return this.code+" "+this.text
}

a = new ProtoError(100) //
console.log(a) // { code: 100,  text: 'foo'}
b=a.fullText() //a.fullText is not a function
```

Пробовал и в синтаксисе ES2015 через class и методы. Статический метод удалось запустить, а у экземпляра класса - выдаёт ту же ошибку.
Почему у моего объекта, видимо, нету функции fullText? Ни гугл, ни классическое описание этих ошибок не помогают.

Comment: видимо должно быть `let ProtoError = function(code) { ...`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нет не должно :-)

Comment: @Grundy значит не должно :-) но вполне может быть :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае неверно использован конструктор.

При возврате из конструктора не примитива, не будет создан объект.

То есть, полученный объект `a` - это не экземпляр типа `ProtoError`, а обычный объект

```
{
  "code": 100,
  "text": "foo"
}
```

У которого нет указанной функции.

Для исправления, не нужно ничего возвращать из конструктора. А поля добавить непосредственно в `this`:

```js
function ProtoError(code) {
  const error = {
    "100": {
      "code": 100,
      "text": "foo"
    },
  };
  this["code"] = error[code].code;
  this["text"] = error[code].text;

}
ProtoError.prototype.fullText = function() {
  return this.code + " " + this.text;
}

a = new ProtoError(100);
console.log(a);
b = a.fullText();
console.log(b);
```

Comment: сорри за вандализм, но ты как всегда быстрее разума)

Comment: @Darth, из-за тебя сбился при написании дополнения :-)

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант, но рассудил, что конструктор по определению возвращает экземпляр класса. Спасибо.

Comment: Смущает, что в таком случае для того, чтобы вернуть объект, нужно перебором проходить по всем полям. Если мне надо всего лишь расширить объект функцией, то как это лучше сделать?

Comment: @mimoprohodil, _Если мне надо всего лишь расширить объект функцией,_ - так и добавь эту функцию в этот объект, также  как ты сейчас добавляешь в прототип, добавляй в сам объект и по сути тебе не нужен конструктор вообще, ну или я не совсем понимаю, что ты хочешь сделать в итоге

Comment: А так можно было? Ну ок, плюсовое прошлое сложно изжить:)
Беда в том, что у меня объекты-то вложенные. Если я расширю error функцией, то конкретная error[code] не будет знать об этой функции. Можно передать параметром и вызывать error.fullText(code), конечно, но не очень красиво, мне кажется.

Comment: @mimoprohodil, просто ты неправильно пользуешься объектами :-) почему тебе просто не передавать два поля в конструктор? тогда внутренний объект вообще уйдет, а прототип заработает